# mail command not found error while script execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

below is the code which I am working on, I am trying to trigger the mail when it enters the if block

```
#!/bin/bash
toaddr2="harigm@gmail.com"
# Main Routine
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -q psoft@123.34.71.238 exit
test=$?
echo "return value  is $test"

set PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
mail $toaddr2 -s "THIS IS THE SUBJECT"
```

When I execute the above code, i am getting **mail command not found**
I am using bash and tried setting up the path as well.

I tried with **mailx** command as well, got the same error
Not worked, any clue from any one, what might be the issue.

Comment: Required dependencies may be missing.. try something like install mailx.. let me know the results..

Comment: Into any regular session type `which mail` and check what is the path of the binary, then you can specify the complete path into your script `/usr/bin/mail $toaddr2 -s ...`

Answer (score 1):

Given that it's a `bash` script, you probably wanted to say

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:${PATH}
```

instead of

```
set PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with:

```
which mail
```

If it is in your path you can have the full path to it in bash.  You could also attempt to use

```
 locate
```

To find mail on your machine.

Comment: When I tried which mail, command I got as No mail command in ENV_PATH

Answer (score 0):

on ubuntu/debian this will solve the issue :  -bash: mail: command not found

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```